# Any Javascript/jQuery libraries for tablesorting, exporting, dynamic row generation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a jJavascript library that can sort columns, export to CSV, and allow for dynamic row creation/deletion (and allow me to use input boxes in them). My main concern is that there is to be ABSOLUTELY NO SERVER-SIDE PROCESSING. As the data entered could be sensitive it is crucial that that data stays local to the computer the data was entered on. I would be willing to build my own CSV export if needed but the other two needs are fixed.

Answer (score 2):

[DataTables](http://datatables.net/) for jQuery is what I use. It has options for client-side only implementation as well as client/server-side.

Comment: I'm familiar with that, but it still requires server processing for the input boxes.

Comment: @Raymond No it doesn't. You can customize every aspect of DataTables and by no means is the DOM dependent on a server-side data source. In order to submit the form, yes, maybe you will need server-side processing. But how else will you save the form data? You could do HTML5 local storage and write your own adapter, for example, if you wanted.

Comment: Would I be able to just have it in the DOM then have a button that could export it all to a csv?